# Evaluate PHP nested string cases to a boolean

Tags: php, eval, assert, assertion

I have a string that is constructed dynamically, can be any length and contain any number of "nested" cases.

An example of one such string could be:

```
(0 && 1)
```

or

```
(0 && ( 1 || ( 0 || 1 ) ) || 1)
```

or even

```
(1 || ( ( (0 || 0) || 1 ) && 0 )
```

I am required to "evalulate" this string and check if the case (or nested cases) represent a true or false.

This can be easily achieved as such:

```
    eval("\$result = (0 && ( 1 || ( 0 || 1 ) ) || 1);");
    var_dump($result);
```

However I consider using `eval` extremely dirty. Is there any way to compile these kinds of strings to a true or false;

Comment: Short of writing your own parser for these types of expressions, I’d look into existing libraries. https://github.com/vanderlee/PHP-Expression looks promising.

Comment: Look into [Symfony's ExpressionLanguage component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html).

Comment: I'd rather not include external libraries as they tend to become outdated and add a lot of bloat considering the "simple" process I would like to use an evaluator for.

Comment: Well, it's either that or building your own parser. Or (carefully) using `eval`. Not exactly sure what you're looking for if none of these options work for you.